# Can someone explain what the actual error is here and how to fix it?

Tags: perl, hash, loops

I'm trying to use a hash in a nested for/foreach loop. [see Source](http://pastebin.com/KYQmLaPD)

With `strict` it says

```
Global symbol "$mapping" requires explicit package name at ./test2.pl line 39. 
Execution of ./test2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Without `strict`,

```
Use of uninitialized value $mapping in hash element at ./test2.pl line 46, <$fh> line 8. 
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test2.pl line 46, <$fh> line 8.
```

`print $hashref->{$mapping}` is empty in the output.

What is the error?

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value $mapping` isn't clear enough?

Comment: I think that some experienced moderator could edit the title of this question to better suit the problem.

Comment: @Victor you can always edit the question/title and someone will come along and approve/disapprove it for you.

Comment: Nice. I didn't knew that (actually "Leave it to the beaver" is something I believe in).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to use a variable called `$mapping` that doesn't exist. There is one called `%mapping` which has an element called `$mapping{$outlook}` but `$mapping` if it existed would be an unrelated scalar, not part of the hash.

It looks like you should use `$hashref->{$mapping{$outlook}}`